# How would I add to table values then show the total on my website

Tags: mysql, database, html

I want to add two table totals together, and then place it on my website here's the code I tried.

```
        <?php
         $host     = "localhost";
             $username = "runerebe_online";
             $password = "***";
             $db_name  = "runerebe_online";
         mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die (mysql_error ());
         mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die(mysql_error());
             $host     = "localhost";
             $username = "runerebe_online2";
             $password = "***";
             $db_name  = "runerebe_online2";
          mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die (mysql_error ());
          mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die(mysql_error());
          $total = "SELECT (online + online2)";
           $rs = mysql_query($total);
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {      
            echo $row['total'];
          }
           mysql_close();
      ?>
```

This is the error printing when I use this

```
    Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/runerebe/public_html/home/index.php on line 63
```

This is line 63, and what it contains

```
    63: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {    
    64:       echo $row['total'];
    65: }
```

Comment: There's a "count" function somewhere out there in php. That should help a bit

Comment: Your query is invalid `SELECT (online + online2)`. What did you want to select?

Comment: I wanted to select the value * from online and add it to the value of online2

Comment: Are online and online2 two databases or two tables in one database?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is invalid. That is why `mysql_query()` fails and returns `FALSE` instead of a resource that is needed for `mysql_fetch_array()` to succeed.

If you need to read two values from two different databases and if a user has permissions granted to do select on both databases and is currently connected to the database `online` you can do that with a statement like this

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(o2.columnname) FROM runerebe_online2.tablename o2) + 
    (SELECT SUM(columnname) FROM tablename) TOTAL
```

Otherwise you need to retrieve two values separately in php like this

```php
//Connect and get a value from db 'runerebe_online'
...
$db_name  = "runerebe_online";
$link1 = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db($db_name, $link1) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT SUM(columnname) subtotal FROM tablename"
$result = mysql_query($total, $link1);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$subtotal1 = $row['subtotal'];
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link1);

//Connect and get a value from db 'runerebe_online2'
...
$db_name  = "runerebe_online2";
$link2 = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("$db_name", $link2) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = "SELECT SUM(columnname) subtotal FROM tablename"
$result = mysql_query($total, $link2);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$subtotal2 = $row['subtotal']
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link1);

$total = $subtotal1 + $subtotal2;
echo $total;
...
```